# Laravel $errors in Blade mystery

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-blade

Can someone explain to me why sometimes I have to use `$errors->all()` and sometimes not?
I'm struggling to find a unique solution for array of error and object $errors.

```
// View 1
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach($errors as $error)
        {{ $error }}<br>
    @endforeach
@endif

// View 2 that sometimes it crashes with:
// "Call to a member function all() on array"
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}<br>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Could it be that you're passing errors to your view manually sometimes? For example: `return view('...')->withErrors(['Your errors']);`

Comment: You must be manually passing errors somewhere either using `with('errors', [...])` in a view response or setting errors in a session manually via `session([ 'errors' => [...])` you need to ensure you always use `withErrors([..])` in either a view response or a redirect response to get the error message bad set properly.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, if there anything different in the controller methods with how you're handling the validation?

Comment: 5.6 @RossWilson and I'm doing nothing on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$errors->all()` using if you validate data via Validator or in the `Request` class. See this [part](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) of the documentation. Laravel share `$errors` variable as `MessageBag` class.

`$errors` as `array` using if in the controller you return something like this:

```
return back()->withErrors([
    'field1' => 'Error in the field 1'
]);
```

In this case Laravel share `$errors` variable as `array`

Comment: I'm using requests, without any redirect.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really do laravel that much but I assume you can always do something like this:

```
  @if (count($errors) > 0)
    @if(is_array($errors))
      @foreach($errors as $error)
        // code
      @endforeach
    @elseif(is_object($errors))
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        //code
      @endforeach
    @endif
  @endif
```